# Can I convert my gulp project into a grunt project ? Is there any tool for the same ?

Tags: angularjs, frontend

I'm creating the dashboard for a company wherein I have the template made up using gulp but I need to convert it into grunt. What is he way in which it can be done. Is there a tool available ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `template`? Your gulp-tasks?

Answer (score 0):

`grunt`and `gulp` are different tasks runners, using completely different plugins (as grunt uses a `config` while vs gulp uses `code`). Sometimes gulp doesn't even have a plugin at all and the goal may be achieved by using the node-module directly.

Therefore no, there is no way of automatically migrating from grunt to gulp. What might be useful for your use-case is [gulp-grunt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-grunt), which allows you to control grunt-tasks from a gulpfile. The counterpart is [grunt-gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-gulp), which controls gulp from a grunt config.